# Dropbox SDK Chooser download file

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I would like to download a file from dropbox into my app i already implemented the Dropbox Drop-in API chooser so i get directed to the dropbox app and can choose a file but i don't know how to download the selected file

```
- (void)didPressChoose{
[[DBChooser defaultChooser] openChooserForLinkType:DBChooserLinkTypePreview
                                fromViewController:self completion:^(NSArray *results)
 {
     if ([results count]) {
         fileurl = [[results[0] link] absoluteString];
         NSLog(@"got results %@", results);
         NSLog(@"link 0 = %@", [[results[0] link] absoluteString]);
     } else {
         // User canceled the action
     }
 }];
```

}

I tried this but i only get a link like "dropbox.com/s/2hro2i45h ..." but for this

```
[self.restClient loadFile:fileurl intoPath:localDir];
```

I need something like "/test.txt"

Comment: What is printed with "link 0 = " ?

Comment: The Link to the file like:www.dropbox.com/something/file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the [documentation for the Dropbox iOS Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios#link-types) lists two different link types. If you want to download the file directly, you should use `DBChooserLinkTypeDirect` instead of `DBChooserLinkTypePreview` as you have in your code.

Second, once you have the direct link, you can use a normal HTTP request on the link to download the file content, e.g., using [`NSURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html). The `loadFile` method you have in your code is for the [Dropbox iOS Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios) which you don't need to use if you're just using the Chooser. That method won't work with the link returned by the Chooser anyway. That method is designed to take a relative path in a user's Dropbox account, but the Chooser is a simpler integration that just gives you a link instead.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure but I have this before calling loadFile on restClient

```
NSString* filePath = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"dropbox://" withString:@""];
[restClient loadFile:filePath intoPath:destinationPath];
```

Comment: This makes out of this :"www.dropbox.com/ugfcfzc76/file.txt" only "file.txt" thats good but if the file is in a Folder that won't work